# Pyhon execute action when application launched via sub-process is closed

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm sure this is already answered but I cannot find anything from the search, maybe I'm not using the correct keywords.

OK, in short > I'm running an application via python sub-process and I would like to execute part of the script after the application is closed.

Initially I was thinking to watch subprocess.pid value in a while loop and when it changes to continue my script. To my surprise however subprocess.pid doesn't change even after the application is already closed.

Any idea why the process.pid doesn't change and how to find out whether the application launched via subprocess command is closed?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use wait(). See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)

I guess pid is not updated because there is no need to lose informations when the process has terminated.